# UWP AppxBundle in Azure DevOps - Error MSB4126 - x86|x64|ARM

Tags: uwp, msbuild, azure-devops

I am trying to use Azure DevOps to build and package my UWP application, but I receive the error `Error MSB4126: The specified solution configuration "Release|x64" is invalid.` when using a custom solution configuration name while trying to creating an appxbundle for all 3 platforms. Using the "Create App Package" option in Visual Studio works fine.

When trying to build and package the appxbundle, the first platform (x86) works correctly because it uses the configuration specified in the MSBuild statement below. But the subsequent x64 or ARM builds fail because, for some reason, it tries to use a default configuration of "Release".

The MSBuild command run by Azure DevOps:

```
"D:\a\1\s\mysolution.sln" /nologo /nr:false /t:"Clean" 
  /p:AppxBundlePlatforms="x86|x64|ARM" 
  /p:AppxPackageDir="D:\a\1\a\AppxPackages\\" 
  /p:AppxBundle=Always 
  /p:UapAppxPackageBuildMode=StoreUpload 
  /p:platform="x86" 
  /p:configuration="App_Release_vNext" 
  /p:VisualStudioVersion="15.0" 
  /p:_MSDeployUserAgent="VSTS_5f450c0a-570b-4d23-8898-51fc0d563e83_build_194_0"
```

The first build in the log where it correctly uses the specified configuration from the MSBuild command:

```
2018-12-13T20:19:17.9223466Z Project "D:\a\1\s\mysolution.sln" on node 1 (Clean target(s)).
2018-12-13T20:19:17.9233806Z ValidateSolutionConfiguration:
2018-12-13T20:19:17.9234638Z   Building solution configuration "App_Release_vNext|x86".
```

The second build in the log where it incorrectly uses a default configuration from the MSBuild command:

```
2018-12-13T20:33:10.9079402Z Project "D:\a\1\s\folder\myproject.csproj" (12) is building "D:\a\1\s\mysolution.sln" (1:2) on node 1 (GetSolutionConfigurationContents target(s)).
2018-12-13T20:33:10.9079592Z ValidateSolutionConfiguration:
2018-12-13T20:33:10.9079706Z   Building solution configuration "Release|x64".
2018-12-13T20:33:10.9864815Z Done Building Project "D:\a\1\s\mysolution.sln" (GetSolutionConfigurationContents target(s)).
2018-12-13T20:33:11.4091745Z ##[error]D:\a\1\s\mysolution.sln.metaproj(0,0): Error MSB4126: The specified solution configuration "Release|x64" is invalid. Please specify a valid solution configuration using the Configuration and Platform properties (e.g. MSBuild.exe Solution.sln /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform="Any CPU") or leave those properties blank to use the default solution configuration.
```

Comment: If you clean your local folders (`git clean -xdf`), and then run the exact same msbuild commands, does it work on your machine?